# What happened to the "add as link" option?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, ide

Why is the [add an existing file as a link](http://visualstudiohacks.com/tips/options/add-an-existing-file-to-a-project-without-copying-it/) feature only available for managed projects?  I can't use the same feature in a vcproj.  Is it because managed projects are built for msbuild, and vcproj files are not?

Comment: Because MS is trying to make C# seem more attractive by making VS as unusable as possible with C++.

Comment: @Jerry, please, VC++ is the best it ever been. MS was so far behind everybody with VC6, now they have one of the best compiler and pretty good IDE.

Comment: because it designed for managed projects. What would you need in C++? IDE doesn't copy files when you add them to the project. where is the problem?

Comment: The compiler has improved, no question about that. I talked specifically about VS (the environment) though, not the compiler. Sadly, the VS 6 environment was substantially better than anything since for doing C++ development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Add As Link* feature is not necessary for VC++ projects (whether managed or not) because VC++ projects do not require all source files to reside strictly within the folder that contains the project.  C# projects, on the other hand, do have this requirement.  So you could say that VC++ **always** adds files as links and **never** copies them.

The price you pay for this flexibility is having to create virtual project folders that don't correspond to real folders on disk and manage them yourself.  This heritage comes from VC6 and believe me plenty of C# programmers envy that flexibility.  To show you the difference between the virtual project folders and the real project folders, toggle "Project -> Show All Files".

Comment: Well, the C# projects do not "require" all source files to reside strictly within the folder that contains the project either. After all you can "add as link" and if you look at into the project file with a text editor, there will be no difference between "link" and "normal" files except for the path. Just even Microsoft realized the virtual structure in projects is confusing and didn't implement it for C#.

Comment: Yes, this whole question is about *Add As Link*.  Perhaps I should have said "require by default".  That is, you have to do something to break the model.  And links are different, they are different in the csproj file (<Link>...</Link>) and they show up with shortcut icons in the solution explorer.  You cannot use "Exclude from project" on them.  Anyway, I too personally prefer the C# real folder model but it took some getting used to.