# Visual Studio 2010 - "Add As Link" option not visibile

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm currently working on a solution which involves 2 projects that share some of the same code. However, when I right click on a project and select "Add->Existing Item", I no longer get the "Add As Link" option on the "Add" drop down button.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express in Window 7 on a 64bit machine and have done this before on Windows XP 32bit. I'm not quite sure why it isn't showing anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [What happened to the "add as link" option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044885/what-happened-to-the-add-as-link-option)

To make a long story short, this option is (normally) only available for managed projects. Can you confirm that your current project is not a managed one ?